# Which tense is apt for the verb 'criticize' in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, errors

Spot the part of the given sentence containing an error.

> The article that she wrote for the last week's Sunday Supplement fairly criticizes the abuse of mobile phones.

The answer provided to me is 'fairly criticizes', however, I don't think there is anything wrong with that. Although the statement talks about an article that was written in the past, I think the present tense 'criticizes' still works because the content of the article is relevant even when the statement was made. So I think there is no error in this sentence.

Am I correct?

Comment: The duplicate question provided does not address your question; yours is not about backshifting. Your sentence uses the [literary present](https://www.thoughtco.com/literary-present-verbs-term-1691251), and it is correct: the article exists ever in the present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're correct. The article is still here, right in this paper I'm holding in my hand, and continues to criticise. I wouldn't say "the speech she gave at the protest last week criticises [...]" is right, because the speech only took place at a given point in time, but an article is here to stay.

Comment: Hello, Divizna. Good second example to show that there is a grammatical choice, and that logic should inform the correct choice from the point of view of semantics. Sometimes (eg 'He didn't know that Phobos was/is Mars's larger moon') backshifting is just a style choice. // There have been quite a few incarnations of this question.